# JPA generic field

Tags: java, generics, jpa

Is it possible to persist a generic field?

I have this property on an `Entity` class

```
...
private T payload;
...

T extends EventMessagePayload
```

and

```
public interface StringPayload extends EventMessagePayload{ 
    String getPayload();
}
```

In my application i persist the field only when is of String type and during the save operation all works great.

When I read the object instead JPA try to create a `String` object but instead is a `StringPaylod`. Is there a way to intercept the creation and handle the object marshalling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA itself does not allow this, but your JPA implementation might allow it. We once did this with Hibernate, and it boilds down to implement your own EntityTuplizer (and a HibernateInterceptor to map your objects back to HibernateEntities).

Answer (score 0):

We can. if the `T` implements `Serializable`

```
@Entity
public class IgsSubject extends BasicObject implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5387429446192609471L;
```